# How can I establish grouping in Django through models?

Tags: python, django

I created a model named MenuItems which will allow for me to enter all of the items that a restaurant has on their menu, later I will use these on the front end. I also created a model name MenuGrouping so that on the front end, I can have Bootstrap tabs show the group_title and under each, show the items in that group. What field should I add in the MenuItems model to associate it to a group? I attempted to use group = models.ForeignKey(MenuGrouping) but then I run into the issue of showing each item in the specific group.

Models.py:

```
class MenuItems(models.Model):

  menu_item_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  menu_item_description = models.TextField()
  menu_item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

  customer_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_on_menu = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('menu_item_title', )


class MenuGrouping(models.Model):
    group_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Is there a relationship that I can add in the MenuGrouping model that I can associate multiple MenuItems?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly that you are trying to make groups like drink, food, desert and ... then here it is:

Each item can be only in one group (I mean soda is a drink and it can't be food too and etc). So what you need to do here is to add a field to **MenuItems** model.

your **MenuItems** should be like this:

```
class MenuItems(models.Model):

    menu_item_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    menu_item_description = models.TextField()
    menu_item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

   customer_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_on_menu = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   group = models.ForeignKey(MenuGrouping)
```

Now to use this in your template first get the groups in view and send them to template and then:

```
{% for group in groups %)

    # add your tabs or just print the group name. or how ever you want.

    Group {{ group.group_title }}:

    # and now you can list the items in this group here

    {% for item in group.menuitems_set.all %}
        Title is: {{ item.menu_item_title }}
        Price is: {{ item.menu_item_price }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need all items to be listed somewhere else out of groups or any other way just send the items to the template too.

Here is the **Many to One** relationship  documentation :
[Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Also you can add a m2m relation to MenuGrouping and add items to each group but then one item can be in multiple groups and for a restaurant menu I can't see how that might happen.